# How to read/estimate Demand System on data

Tags: microeconomics, applied-econometrics, micro-data, demand-system-estimation

I have difficulties understanding the concept of Almost Ideal Demand System or, most probably, I have a problem of how to perform microeconomic estimates from data, in general...

So my data look like this:

| ID | Good1 | Good2 | Good3 | Good4 | Price1 | Price2 | Price3 | Price4 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 2 | **0** | **0** | **0** | 4 | 2 | 3 | 2 | day1 |
| ID2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 3 | 2 | day1 |
| ID3 | **0** | 1 | 2 | **0** | 3 | 5 | 4 | 2 | day2 |

I have the **ID** of a transaction, how many goods were bought during that transaction, prices of all the goods, and the date. And what *I would like to know* is **how the quantity demanded depends on prices and whether goods are complements or substitutes**, therefore approximating *elasticity of substitution* or (rather) *price elasticities*, cross and self...

In short, there are multiple possible approaches how to solve this question and I would like to ask you **what should I do** *if I want to measure it*: **What equation to estimate and by which estimator (OLS?)**

#### OPTION A: Simple regression

$$ ln(Good_i) = \sum_j \beta_{ij} * ln(Price_{ij}) + \epsilon_i $$

Where $\beta_j$ is price elasticity of $Good_i$ with respect to $Price_j$, right? Is this good estimate or not?

Should this be used in panel or some form of time series?

#### OPTION B: Elasticity equation

$$\ln \left( \frac{Good_q}{Good_r} \right) = \sigma_{qr} \ln \left( \frac{Price_q}{Price_r} \right) + \epsilon$$

Where $\sigma_{qr} $ would be elasticity of substitution between

In which case I would have problem with those abundant zeros. So I don't think I could use it. I was thinking, maybe I could only work with ratios without zero in denominator so, for example, in **ID1** consider the ratio $Good_2 / Good_1$ and within **ID3** consider the ratio $Good_1 / Good_3$... But I don't know...

#### OPTION C: Demand system - the hardest

Here I understand I have to prepare a new variable: the budget ratio, meaning $M_i = \sum P_i x_i $ and then I would divide each $Good$ by this $M$, therefore, obtaining $s_i = Good_i / M_i$. Is that so?

Then I could estimate the following equation:

$$s_i = \alpha_i + \sum_j \gamma_{ij} * ln(P_j) + \psi_i * ln(M / INDEX) $$

But... Is the $M$ here the same as $M_i$ previously? Is $\gamma_{ij}$ interpretation-wise the same as $\beta_{ij}$ from **OPTION A**, meaning it tells me the price elasticity? What is $\psi_i$?

#### OPTION D: Slutsky equation

I have found out a video from @EconJohn about estimating Slutsky equation from data: [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hymzMoHeqi4&t=13s)

He uses the following equation (in translation to my notation):

$$ Good_i = \sum_j \beta_{ij} * ln(Price_{ij}) + \gamma_i * M_i + \epsilon_i $$

And then he plugs the results into Slutsky equation:

$$\frac{\partial x_i^*}{\partial P_j} = \frac{\partial \widetilde{x_i}}{\partial P_j} - \frac{\partial x_i^*}{\partial M_i}* \widetilde{x_j}$$

From this he could technically get Slutsky matrix since he can make this eq. for each good and price... The question, however, is: Am I able to construct $M_i$ from my data as $\sum Good_i Price_i$ per transaction?

#### OPTION E: Hurdle model

Those zeroes seem to be really problematic, because I cannot then distinguish if a good was perfect substitute for a consumer of just an economic bad... Is there some possibility to filter them out, probably using hurdle model? Or just omitting them at all? Could I go for option B when I have dealt with zeroes by this way?

**Thank you very much for help**. I am completely lost on this. I have tried to read Varian but it did not help me much.